# Using hook_js_alter to change localsettings variable in the autologout module drupal

Tags: hooks, javascript

I want to know how to use hook_js_alter to change the localSettings variable in autologout.js.

In autologout.module in line number ( 377 - 389)

```
$settings = array(
    'timeout' => $refresh_only ? ($timeout * 500) : ($timeout * 1000),
    'timeout_padding' => $timeout_padding * 1000,
    'message' => t('@msg', array('@msg' => $msg)),
    'redirect_url' => url($redirect_url, array('query' => $redirect_query)),
    'title' => t('@name Alert', array('@name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal'))),
    'refresh_only' => $refresh_only,
    'no_dialog' => $no_dialog,
  );
drupal_add_js(array('autologout' => $settings), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'autologout') . "/autologout.js");
```

In this it passes the settings variable to the javascript file.

I want to change
" 'title' => t('@name Alert', array('@name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')))," attribute using "hook_js_alter" in my custom module so that javscript takes the new value.

Comment: Replace the file if you need to, monkey patch the appropriate method if you don't. Where are you stuck exactly? Please edit the question to provide more details

Comment: Hello Clive, I have edited the question. Can you please check if this would suffice?

Comment: Thanks Clive, please let me know the best possible solution in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the `$javascript` array passed to `hook_js_alter()` is similar to the following one. (I reported only the relevant part of the array.)

```
array(
  'settings' => array(
    'data' => array(
      0 => array('basePath' => '/'),
      1 => array ('pathPrefix' => ''),
      2 => array('ajaxPageState' => array ('theme' => 'bartik', 'theme_token' => 'oFpiDA70-NnnvSdIL6bFt1oLccvTT5SZeOp3G34cOfs')),
      3 => array ('overlay' => array('paths' => array('admin' => 'node/*/edit node/*/delete node/*/revisions node/*/revisions/*/revert node/*/revisions/*/delete node/add node/add/* overlay/dismiss-message user/*/shortcuts admin admin/* batch taxonomy/term/*/edit user/*/cancel user/*/edit user/*/edit/*', 'non_admin' => 'admin/structure/block/demo/* admin/reports/status/php'))),
      4 => array('overlay' => array('pathPrefixes' => array())),
      5 => array('overlay' => array('ajaxCallback' => 'overlay-ajax'))
    ),
    'type' => 'setting',
    'scope' => 'header',
    'group' => -100,
    'every_page' => true,
    'weight' => 0
  )
  // ...
);
```

I would use the following code for `hook_js_alter()`.

```
if (isset($javascript['settings']['data']) && is_array($javascript['settings']['data'])) {
  foreach ($javascript['settings']['data'] as $index => $settings) {
    if (isset($settings['autologout']['title']) && is_array($settings['autologout'])) {
      $javascript['settings']['data'][$index]['autologout']['title'] = 'Your value';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```